# SQL which generates sequence of alphabets between given start and end point

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a SQL which generates sequence of alphabets between given start and end point.

Like,for `Start='C' End='G'` output should be

```
C
D
E
F
G
```

Comment: Clue: use the ASCII()  and CHAR() funtions

Comment: @borjab  you ment `CHR()` right?

Comment: Yes. it is. generally speaking, in the computer programming world, the answer to an `Is this possible` question is almost *always* `yes`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Sure: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/chr.php

Comment: Thanks Borjab. It works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select chr(ascii('C') + level - 1) 
from dual
connect by ascii('C') + level - 1 <= ascii('G');
```

Using `connect by` like this (no `start with` and an end condition that only depends on the level) is undocumented (and unsupported) so it might break any time (although I'm not aware of any version where this would not work).

Starting with 11.2 you can also use a recursive common table expression:

```
with letters (letter, inc) as (
   select 'C', 1 as inc
   from dual
   union all
   select chr(ascii('C') + p.inc), p.inc + 1
   from letters p
   where p.inc < 5
)
select letter
from letters;
```

Comment: `level - 1` if `C` and `G` need to be included in the output as well

Comment: Doesn't oracle fully supports recurcive CTEs? why the need for an undocumented feature?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: `connect by` **is** a documented and supported feature. Only the usage without a `start with` is not (I changed my explanation)

Comment: I'm an sql server guy myself, I just thought it's strange suggesting someone to use an undocumented feature. those tend to be unreliable and may be removed in any given update.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: using `connect by` like that is a pretty common hack to be used as a "series generator" in the Oracle world. And although this `connect by` usage is not "supported" I very much doubt Oracle will ever remove it. I just added the comment in case someone complains that it *is* unsupported.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name quiet useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked

```
WITH X AS
(SELECT 'C' as St, 'G' as En FROM dual)
SELECT CHR(ASCII(X.St)+ROWNUM-1)
FROM X
CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=(ASCII(X.En)-ASCII(X.St)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified @a_horse_with_no_name answer as below

```
WITH X(lettr) AS 
(SELECT 'C' lettr FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT CHR(ASCII(X.lettr)+1) letter
 FROM X 
 WHERE ASCII(X.lettr)<ASCII('G'))
 SELECT * FROM X
```